# Bitcoinj OverlappingFileLockException in docker compose

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, filesystems

I am testing a Bitcoinj application in docker compose, with 2 wallets. One starts correctly, second one throws a `Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.bitcoinj.store.BlockStoreException: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException`.

Wallet and SPV files are mounted into each docker containers and are located in, from workspace root, `./docker-volumes/wallet-app/...` and `./docker-volumes/wallet-test/...`.

As far as I understand `OverlappingFileLockException` should be thrown when same JVM tries to lock the same file multiple times. In my case it is thrown when 2 containers seemingly lock 2 different files in different directories, so it seems like a docker compose issue, not Bitcoinj or other code.

My volumes are mounted as `- ./docker-volumes/wallet-app:/wallet-app` and `- ./docker-volumes/wallet-test:/wallet-test` in docker-compose.yml

Either one of the wallets starts correctly on its own.

After restarting crashed container with `docker-compose restart wallet-...` a couple times - it starts fine and I can run tests.

I suspect it has to do with volume mounts (although my containers should still run in 2 separate JVMs I would imagine), but have not been able to find anything particularly useful in docker docs. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:
relevant docker-compose.yml services

```
version: '3'
services:

  listener:
    image: listener:0.1
    environment:
    - NOTIFIER_URL=http://notifications:9000
    - COIN_NET=test
    - WALLET_PATH=/wallet
    - MONGO_HOST=mongo
    - MONGO_PORT=27017
    - MONGO_DB=test_db
    - RMQ_HOST=rabbit
    - RMQ_PORT=5672
    - RMQ_USERNAME=user
    - RMQ_PASSWORD=password
    - RMQ_ROUTING=event_producer
    - RMQ_EXCHANGE=amq.direct
    volumes:
    - ./docker-volumes/wallet-app:/wallet
    depends_on:
    - mongo
    - notifications
    - rabbit

  listener-test:
    image: test:0.1
    volumes:
    - ./docker-volumes/wallet-test:/wallet-test
```

Comment: I cannot understand what is going on with just these info, maybe supply your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: sure. These are the 2 services that run wallets that have issues. listener-test runs tests on its entry point.

Comment: this setup isn't even remotely what I was expecting.. It probably has little to do with docker. AFAIK docker volume driver has no issue with file locks, unless the host FS is poor in this regard (e.g. ancient FAT system, nfs, etc)... I'd suggest looking at application itself.